# Use normal spacing within a minipage (same as outside)

Tags: spacing, lists, minipage, paragraphs

I was wondering how to have the contents of a `minipage` look exactly the same as “normal” text (i. e. with respect to spacing, indents etc.). These `minipage`s can contain arbitrary content such as section headings, lists, paragraphs etc.

Looking at `latex.ltx`, it seems to me that the relevant definition is

```
\def\@iiiminipage#1#2[#3]#4{%
  \leavevmode
  \@pboxswfalse
  \setlength\@tempdima{#4}%
  \def\@mpargs{{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}}%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox\bgroup
    \color@begingroup
      \hsize\@tempdima
      \textwidth\hsize \columnwidth\hsize
      \@parboxrestore
      \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}\def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}\c@mpfootnote\z@
      \let\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
      \let\@listdepth\@mplistdepth \@mplistdepth\z@
      \@minipagerestore
      \@setminipage}
 \let\@minipagerestore=\relax
```

In there, I see `\@arrayparboxrestore`, which seems to be defined as

```
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue
  \lineskip\normallineskip
  \lineskiplimit\normallineskiplimit
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}
\def\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\let\\\@normalcr}
```

So I thought to get a “`minipage` with normal spacing”, I could do something like

```
\newenvironment{myminipage}[1]%
    {\let\@parboxrestore\relax\begin{minipage}{#1}}%
    {\end{minipage}}
```

(I don’t need the optional `minipage` arguments.) Will this achieve my goal without adverse effects?

Comment: I posted an answer but short version: dragons lurk there:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sigh, don’t they always in LaTeX? ;-)

Comment: however the basic core of the answer is that if you just have a version of arrayparboxrestore that doesn't reset the skips, it is probably safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly that definition will do what you want, just mean that formatting settings inherit from the outside (mostly minipage is designed with the explicit intention of *not* having that inheritance).

You may however want to re-instate the resetting of `\everypar` as otherwise the use of this environment at the start of a section or list item will be well defined but probably not what you want.

```
\everypar{}
```

If you use the environment inside `tabbing` you may also want to restore the accent commands

```
\let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
```

otherwise `\'` and friends will try to be the `tabbing` commands but fail to work as they are inside the nested box.

You also want to keep

```
 \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
```

Or strange things will happen if you use the environment at the start of a section or anywhere inside a table.

You may or may not want to re-instate `\\`

```
\let\\\@normalcr
```

depending on your use. If you use this environment in a `tabular` `c` column then that would make `\\` be a newline rather than ending the table row (and generating an error as it is inside a box)  But on the other hand if outside the new evironment you had a `center` or `flushright` environment you woudl want to keep the outer definition of `\\` as (unlike `minipage`) the non-justified setting is inherited.

---

An example where the `\everypar` code designed to inhibit indentation after a section heading gets incorrectly applied:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myminipage}[1]%
    {\let\@parboxrestore\relax\begin{minipage}{#1}}%
    {\end{minipage}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\section{zzz}
\begin{minipage}{1cm}
  hello

  goodbye

  hello again
\end{minipage}

 zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz

 zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz

\section{www}
\begin{myminipage}{1cm}
  hello

  goodbye

  hello again
\end{myminipage}

 zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz

 zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz zz zzz






\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, this is very helpful! Could you explain a tiny bit more about `\everypar{}`? I haven’t noticed any significant differences apart from the presence (or absence) of the list item bullet.

Comment: @Socob well that's possibly the main problem but losing the item label in an itemised list seems rather bad (actually some of the other places for `\everypar` aren't quite as bad as I was thinking as mostly the outer `\leavevmode` gets you out of trouble. I may post some examples later. Anotehr thing I didn't mention is any tabular inside the minipage will have broken `p` columns unless you restote arrayparboxrestore inside the environment

Comment: @Socob I added an example, probably not the worst thing that can happen but thinking how to trigger all the possible things that are not "made safe" if you disable parbox restore is a bit tricky:-)

Comment: The item label wasn’t actually disappearing for me for `\let\@parboxrestore\relax`, but for the other case. But I suppose that’s because I used `\let\@parboxrestore\relax\everypar{}` instead of `\def\@parboxrestore{\everypar{}}`…

Comment: @Socob ah yes I see.

Comment: I just realized that `\linewidth\hsize` is probably also something that I want to keep, otherwise `\linewidth` will still contain the outer value even within `myminipage`. In fact, that seems to be really important when `myminipage` contains lists.